# Why is the copy constructor not called in this C++ code?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, move-constructor

I have a simple class Employee that has three strings (first, middle and last names) and defines copy and move constructors and assignment operators and prints a text when each one is called. I also have this code in my main class

```
int main() {
    Employee e = getEmp();

    return 0;
}

Employee getEmp() {
    Employee emp("John","","Smith");
    return emp;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
This is Employee constructor
This is Employee destructor
```

So the copy or move constructors are never called and only one Employee is created, whereas I was expecting a call to the move constructor when getEmp() returns. What is happening?

Comment: #RVO# A topic that has been discussed million times here...

Comment: Return value optimization is happening: search for RVO

Comment: Shouldn't RVO call the move constructor?

Comment: @Kam: Nope. RVO (or more generally, copy elision) eliminates copy and move constructor calls entirely, by constructing the source object in the memory location of the destination object.

Comment: Thanks guys! Sorry for the duplicate question